# run python in shell and redirect python print

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell script, which runs a python file and does some log. I first redirect all stdout and stderr to a specific file. but noticed that, a print statement in python does not show their print result to my specific log file.
This is my shell file:

```
date=$(date +"%D")

exec 3>&1
exec 4>&2
exec 1>>/root/shell/auto.log
exec 2>>/root/shell/auto.log

header=$(printf "%-10s" "=")
echo "${header}${date}--start${header}"| sed "s/ /=/g"

python /root/shell/someAuto.py

echo "${header}${date}--end${header}"| sed "s/ /=/g"
exec 1>&3
exec 2>&4
```

I add some demo case to redo this problem.The simple python file can be that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
import sys
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(5)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

when start run shell script, `tail -f auto.log`, start headers print quickly and success, but wait longer than every 5 secs, no print result show, i don't know why..
here some log.The reason why I always KeyboardInterrupt is that it run so long, it's not normal, so I stop it.

```
==========06/16/20--start==========
0
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/shell/testLog.py", line 6, in <module>
    time.sleep(5)
KeyboardInterrupt
==========06/16/20--end==========
==========06/16/20--start==========
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/shell/testLog.py", line 6, in <module>
    time.sleep(5)
KeyboardInterrupt
==========06/16/20--end==========
==========06/16/20--start==========
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/shell/testLog.py", line 6, in <module>
    time.sleep(5)
KeyboardInterrupt
==========06/16/20--end==========
```

Comment: The Python output is going to your terminal instead?

Comment: I don't want to write code in python file to specific where to print, hope other method to solve

Comment: But is that what's happening when you run your shell script?

Comment: python print output not show in my terminal, just when I use ctrl+c to exit my script running, i notice some output in log file, but some message lost, and can't find the rule which print result will going in log file.

Comment: Would you mind showing the Python file and the contents of the log file after you run your script?

Comment: I notice you run the script as root, which is not good practice. Do not use the name of Root in vain...

Comment: thank you, I add some info.